# Get implode error when reading from array

Tags: php, fwrite, implode

I'm trying to delete an user out of a file.
This is how I delete the user from my array:

```
if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {
    $id = key($_GET['delete']);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($liste); $i++) {
        if ("$i" == "$id") {
            array_splice($liste, $id, 1);
        } else {
            //do something
        }
    }
    saveDataToFile('passwd.txt', '$liste');
}
```

Then I use an other function to write it in a file. But I always get the error

```
implode(): Invalid arguments passed
```

This is the function.

```
      function saveDataToFile($fileName, $liste){
    $file=fopen($fileName,"w");
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($liste); $i++) {
        $zArray=$liste[$i]; 
        $zeile=implode("|", $zArray);
        if(strlen($zeile) > 0){ 
            $zeile=$zeile."\r\n"; 
            fwrite($file, $zeile);
        }
    }
    fclose($file);
}
```

**update**
I also found out that it does delete everytime I refresh.
I think I need a break when it deleted the one I want. But the break doesn't work.

Comment: `fclose($datei);` has to be `fclose($file);`

Answer (score 0):

You pass $liste as a string not array, here

```
saveDataToFile('passwd.txt', '$liste');
```

May this work with you:

```
saveDataToFile('passwd.txt', $liste);
```

Comment: Oh, you're right. Implode error is gone now. But now the second last user entries get deleted